# How do I configure vhost to read system path when enabled

Tags: apache2, config, virtualhost, vhosts

I'm trying to set up a vhost to allow a specific file system path beneath the public directory.

Current Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "..etc/www/mysite.com/public_html"
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to include the path "../etc/bin/zend/library" inside "../etc/www/mysite.com/library"
I am not sure if I need to change the documentroot to beneath the public_html and reference all public traffic to public_html or if I can use a mod_rewrite or directory to include a system directory. Also the directory should only be run/read; no write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `Alias`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "..etc/www/mysite.com/public_html"
    Alias /library ../etc/bin/zend/library
</VirtualHost>
```

So if you go to `http://mysite.com/library`, it will serve the contents from `../etc/bin/zend/library`

Comment: only problem is the directory should not be accessible publicly. I'm trying to make the directory locally visible/accessible only.

Comment: @MatthewSprankle what do you mean by "locally"? via a script in the document root or via localhost?

Comment: that brings the idea of creating another virtual host that is only accessible through local sites. I'm trying to push/pull files to the different virtual hosts via the system. Trying to create a repository of libraries that a number of sites can run off of locally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not an apache issue ...
  You should create a symbolic link :

```
cd .etc/www/mysite.com/
ln -s ../etc/bin/zend/library library
```

it should work.

régards

Mimiz